# When you don't respect your parents, no outsider will not respect them either. Is there a actual proverb or idiom or expression for the above quote

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

> - When you don't respect your parents, no outsider, not even your spouse, will respect them either.
>     OR
> - When you don't respect your spouse, no one, even including your own children, will respect them either.
>     OR
> - When you don't respect your subordinates, no one from other departments, not even their subordinates or clients, will respect them either.
>     OR
> - When you don't respect your compatriots, no other nationals will respect them either.

Is there an actual proverb or idiom or expression for the above quote?

Comment: I think this needs some editing.

Comment: You call this a quote. Can you give the source for this quote, either the author and work, or a direct link?

Comment: If you're looking for a common English proverb/idiom for this concept, I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 1):

leading by example
setting a good example for others to follow

> to act in a way that shows others how to act
>  [Merriam-Webster
>   Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead%20by%20example)
>
> set an example
>  Also,set a good or bad example. Behave in a way
>   that should (or will) be imitated, as in Dad was always telling Bill
>   to set a good example for his younger brother, or They were afraid of
>   setting a bad example for the other nations.
>  [The American
>   Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/set-an-example)